# Vowel counter in a text file

Tags: python-3.x

```
import sys
import string
from collections import Counter
vowels = "aeiouy"
try:
    in_file = open("Vowels.txt","r")
    count = {x:sum([1 for char in vowels if char==x])for x in 'aeiouy'}
    print(count)

except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The text file is not found")
        sys.exit(1)
in_file.close()
```

In my file I have the words Mississippi,California, Wisconsin and i'm trying to do is count how many vowels are in each vowel and output that, but every time I get 1 for every single vowel and the output changes every time like:
{'a': 1, 'u': 1, 'o': 1, 'y': 1, 'i': 1, 'e': 1}

{'o': 1, 'y': 1, 'e': 1, 'a': 1, 'i': 1, 'u': 1}

Comment: From when did they add `y` to vowels??

Comment: That's how I learned it: aeiou and sometimes y

Comment: lol :). What do you mean by sometimes `y`. So `y` is a vowel and sometimes not?

Comment: Yeah that's how I learned it in school :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
count = {x:sum([1 for char in vowels if char==x])for x in 'aeiouy'}
```

with

```
txt = in_file.read()
count = {x:sum([1 for char in txt if char==x])for x in 'aeiouy'}
```

The first line is what actually reads the file.  The second line is very much like your line except for the presence of `txt`.

Putting it all together and using python's `with` functionality:

```
try:
    with open("Vowels.txt","r") as in_file:
        txt = in_file.read()
        count = {x:sum([1 for char in txt if char==x])for x in 'aeiouy'}
        print(count)
except IOError:
        print("The text file is not found")
        sys.exit(1)
```

For your sample input, the output is:

```
{'a': 2, 'e': 0, 'i': 8, 'o': 2, 'u': 0, 'y': 0}
```

#### Like the above but ordered

Dictionaries are unordered.  If you want an ordered list, substitute in the line:

```
 count = [ [x,sum([1 for char in txt if char==x])] for x in 'aeiouy']
```

With the above, the output is a list of lists:

```
[['a', 2], ['e', 0], ['i', 8], ['o', 2], ['u', 0], ['y', 0]]
```

Lists retain their order.

Comment: I see you replaced x with v and added dict after the = sign in count is there a reason for that?

Comment: @Marcos OK.  I just revised the answer to highlight the minimum changes required.

Comment: That makes it much simpler thank you, but I question about my output is there anyway to make it always aeiouy in that order and not random like how I posted it?

Comment: To keep order, you can either use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) or don't use a dict at all and use a list or tuple instead.  Which you chose depends on how you ultimately want to use the information.

Comment: @Marcos OK.  I added an example using lists.